# What would be the likelihood that when the Milky Way formed, it would be composed entirely of sun-like stars?

Tags: astrophysics, stars, galaxies

So, what would be the likelihood that when the Milky Way formed, it would be composed entirely of sun-like stars? What was the configuration of the gas, the history of the primordial stars, for this to happen?

Comment: Given the number and variety of stars, why would think there is any possibility that does not converge to 0 for that to happen?

Comment: This is too hypothetical. Single mass populations do not form in nature. Perhaps a more interesting question is why we can rule your scenario out.

Comment: @Kosci The probability, of course, is scanty. But it seems to me that it is non-zero. Can you justify why the probability should be strictly zero?

Comment: @ProfRob Not "are not formed", but "the probability of the formation of a single mass population is so small that it can be neglected." It seems to me. I don't think the probability is strictly zero. For this, the process must be prohibited by physical laws.

Comment: What are you quoting?

Comment: @ProfRob You said "Single mass populations do not form in nature". I say: "the probability of the formation of a single mass population is so small that it can be neglected". These are two different things. "Not formed" means that the probability is strictly zero.

Comment: @josephh What exactly is it about?

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress Ok, fair enough, it is not strictly zero. Still, it is negligible, analogously (although may in a total different order of magnitude, but both close to 0) to the often quoted probability of a floor collecting all the heat beneath a ball by chance to let the latter bounce into the air. Begs the question, what you find interesting about such a probability?

Comment: Different people have very different views on what a negligible but non-zero probability means. Mathematicians and philosophers would just regard it as non-zero (for things that actually approach zero in the limit they have the term of art "almost never"). Many physicists would say events that almost certainly will never happen in the history of the observable universe simply don't happen. It might be good if the question makes it clear that it seems to come from the mathematical rather than practical side.

Comment: @Anders Sandberg I agree. But if you take seriously the idea of an infinite universe, then even events, the probability of which is very close to zero, will happen an infinite number of times. But this is just philosophical reasoning. We can only see the observable universe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many factors in the formation of stars that determine their type and size. Before stars form, they are called [protostars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protostar), which are collections of gas that have collapsed from large molecular clouds. The protostar's phase of evolution lasts about 100,000 years where over time, gravitational forces and pressure increase, causing the protostar to collapse into a star.

The amount of gas that comes together as such, to form each star is pretty much random, due to the dynamic conditions during the evolution of the universe. Given this, and the fact that there is no preference at all for the formation of "sun-like" (G-type) stars, the probability that the milky way or any galaxy would be composed exclusively of sun-type stars is practically zero.

Note that there are about 100,000,000,000 stars in the Milky Way. The probability that any one of these is a G-type (like the sun) star is $0.07$ (7% of stars in the Milky way are G-type), meaning the probability is $$P\approx 0.07^{100,000,000,000} \rightarrow 0$$ for all of them to be G-type.

Comment: Practically, but not strictly, zero.

Comment: It would be a very very small one though.

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean when you say: "This appears to be your opinion. What you say is not backed up by any scientific studies"?

Comment: Never mind that. I thought you were quoting from some study. I will delete that particular comment. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This is not quite the answer to your question, since nobody can reliably put a numerical probability on something that has never been observed to occur in nature. i.e. A close-to single-mass population has never been observed as the outcome of a star formation process and we have never seen another galaxies made exclusively of solar-type stars. This is also impossible to answer theoretically at present because there is no accepted first-principles explanation of why the initial mass function looks the way it does.

However, we can certainly rule out that this occurred in the Milky Way.

We don't know exactly how many population III (metal-free) stars were initially born in our Galaxy$^1$, or what fraction of them were solar-type stars. However, we do know that the number of population III stars must have been large and that they *cannot* all have been solar-type stars, since that would not explain the chemical enrichment patterns seen in the [extremely metal-poor](https://phys.org/news/2019-04-ultra-metal-poor-star.html), ancient population II stars.

These stars, formed from almost pristine gas, polluted only by the detritus of the first stars, have trace amounts of carbon, calcium, silicon, magnesium and iron ([Bonifacio et l. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.03935); [Francois et al. 2020](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.03994)).

These elements could not be produced by solar-type population III stars, since (i) solar-type stars are not massive enough to ever synthesise Mg, Ca, Si or Fe; (ii) they would have lifetimes of about 10 billion years and so could not enrich the oldest population II stars.

So *we know* that many *massive* stars must have been amongst the first generation of stars born in the Milky Way and there is **zero** probability that all the first stars in the Milky Way were of solar type.

$^1$ Note that the "Milky Way" did not form monolithically, so the answer above really applies to the separate components that came together to make the Milky Way.

Comment: Most likely I need to clarify my question a little. For example, what would be the probability that all Population I stars in the Milky Way were sun-like? Or, a more general question, was it possible such an evolution of the Milky Way, as a result of which it would consist mainly (up to 90 percent) of sun-like stars?

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress the problem is your use of tenses. What is the probability...   is a different (and answerable) question to "What would the probability...", which is unanswerable other than to say it is vanishingly tiny but unquantifiable.

Comment: My question is about exactly "what would be the probability." What is the probability I know. This is zero, since the observations provide a definite answer. But if we imagine the formation of the Galaxy anew, what would be the probability of its transformation into a "G-galaxy"? I think very close to zero, since this required very finely tuned and unlikely conditions and a sequence of processes.

Answer (score 1):

In the solar neighbourhood G-type stars are about $p\approx $ 7%. So were you to generate $N$ stars entirely randomly and independently, the probability of them all being G-type would be $0.07^N$. For $N=10^{11}$ this is $10^{-15490195998.6}\approx 0 $. Changing the exact numbers does not change the conclusion much.

Clearly to get a G-type galaxy you need to somehow ensure that the conditions are astonishingly regular during star formation so you only get stars in a certain, very narrow yet fairly heavyish, mass band. The other answers give some good reasons for why this is unlikely both because of astrochemical evolution (the early Milky Way had different kinds of stars) and the randomness of the turbulent gas collapse process.

Comment: Thank you! That is, the probability, although not strictly zero, is practically indistinguishable from zero.

Comment: The number of population III stars was not $10^{11}$ and it is unknown what fraction of them were solar-type. Still, for any sensible choice of $x^N$ you get zero.

Comment: @ProfRob Still, it's not exactly zero.

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress so what? Is your question really "is it exactly zero"? Yes, the probability that all the first stars in our Milky Way were solar type is *exactly* zero. The probability that if you made a new Milky Way that all the first stars would be solar-type is tiny, but unquantifiable.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the Milky Way (or, at least, a cluster of stars that later became the Milky Way) was formed soon after the Big Bang.

We know this because we have found several stars in the Milky Way that are estimated to be more than $13$ billion years old. These old stars are called [Population II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_population) stars and they contain very, very small amounts of elements other than hydrogen and helium - cosmologists describe them as [metal-poor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallicity) stars. We think that there was an even earlier generation of stars called Population III, which were made up of *only* hydrogen and helium (which were the elements formed in the Big Bang). Because of their composition, these first stars would have been large and bright with short lifetimes, which is why none of them have survived to the present era.

The Sun, on the other hand, is only about $4.6$ billion years old, and is a Population I star. It is relatively rich in elements heavier than hydrogen and helium (although hydrogen and helium still make up about $98\%$ of the mass of the sun). These heavier elements were formed in the final super-nova stages of one or more generations of stars that preceded the Sun.

So we believe the metal-poor Population II and Population III stars that formed the original Milky Way would have been larger, brighter, bluer and shorter-lived than the Sun.

If you are interested in this topic, I can recommend “First Light: Switching On Stars at the Dawn of Time” by Emma Chapman.

Comment: But what would be the probability that all the stars of Population I would be sun-like?

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress Population I stars are the latest generation of stars. Some of then are like the sun, some of them are much larger, some of them are much smaller. But the *original* primordial stars that formed the Milky Way were Population II and III and were very different from the Sun.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. But still, what would be the probability that Population I stars would all be similar to the Sun and among them there would be no stars of other sizes and masses?

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress What is the probability that everyone on Earth could be similar to you ? Well, it’s smaller than that because there are more stars in the Milky Way than there are people on Earth.